# BCP export placing NULL character in place of blanks

Tags: format, bcp

I am executing a BCP export:

```
bcp "exec SourceDatabase.dbo.usp_Select_CLIENT_DailyFile_BCP" queryout "outbox\CLIENT_%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%.dat" -f dailyfile.fmt -S SQLSVR10 -T -q >>%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%.log
```

Here is the format file in question:

```
9.0
80
1       SQLCHAR       0       20      "|"   1     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR       0       20      "|"   2     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR       0       2       "|"   3     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx3                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR       0       20      "|"   4     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx4                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5       SQLCHAR       0       20      "|"   5     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
6       SQLCHAR       0       3       "|"   6     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
7       SQLCHAR       0       2       "|"   7     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
8       SQLCHAR       0       8       "|"   8     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx8                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
9       SQLCHAR       0       8       "|"   9     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx9                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
10      SQLCHAR       0       8       "|"   10    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx10                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
11      SQLCHAR       0       8       "|"   11    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx11                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
12      SQLCHAR       0       8       "|"   12    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx12                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
13      SQLCHAR       0       8       "|"   13    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx13                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
14      SQLCHAR       0       8       "|"   14    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx14                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
15      SQLCHAR       0       8       "|"   15    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx15                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
16      SQLCHAR       0       8       "|"   16    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx16                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
17      SQLCHAR       0       8       "|"   17    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx17                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
18      SQLCHAR       0       8       "|"   18    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx18                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
19      SQLCHAR       0       8       "|"   19    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx19                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
20      SQLCHAR       0       8       "|"   20    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx20                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
21      SQLCHAR       0       5       "|"   21    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx21                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
22      SQLCHAR       0       50      "|"   22    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx22                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
23      SQLCHAR       0       1       "|"   23    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx23                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
24      SQLCHAR       0       2       "|"   24    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx24                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
25      SQLCHAR       0       50      "|"   25    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx25                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
26      SQLCHAR       0       5       "|"   26    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx26                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
27      SQLCHAR       0       1       "|"   27    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx27                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
28      SQLCHAR       0       25      "|"   28    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx28                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
29      SQLCHAR       0       25      "|"   29    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx29                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
30      SQLCHAR       0       50      "|"   30    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx30                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
31      SQLCHAR       0       5       "|"   31    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx31                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
32      SQLCHAR       0       50      "|"   32    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx32                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
33      SQLCHAR       0       50      "|"   33    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx33                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
34      SQLCHAR       0       50      "|"   34    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx34                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
35      SQLCHAR       0       50      "|"   35    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx35                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
36      SQLCHAR       0       11      "|"   36    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx36                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
37      SQLCHAR       0       11      "|"   37    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx37                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
38      SQLCHAR       0       50      "|"   38    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx38                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
39      SQLCHAR       0       50      "|"   39    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx39                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
40      SQLCHAR       0       50      "|"   40    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx40                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
41      SQLCHAR       0       50      "|"   41    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx41                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
42      SQLCHAR       0       25      "|"   42    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx42                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
43      SQLCHAR       0       2       "|"   43    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx43                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
44      SQLCHAR       0       10      "|"   44    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx44                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
45      SQLCHAR       0       20      "|"   45    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx45                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
46      SQLCHAR       0       50      "|"   46    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx46                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
47      SQLCHAR       0       25      "|"   47    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx47                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
48      SQLCHAR       0       60      "|"   48    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx48                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
49      SQLCHAR       0       50      "|"   49    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx49                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
50      SQLCHAR       0       35      "|"   50    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx50                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
51      SQLCHAR       0       35      "|"   51    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx51                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
52      SQLCHAR       0       35      "|"   52    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx52                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
53      SQLCHAR       0       35      "|"   53    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx53                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
54      SQLCHAR       0       25      "|"   54    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx54                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
55      SQLCHAR       0       2       "|"   55    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx55                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
56      SQLCHAR       0       10      "|"   56    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx56                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
57      SQLCHAR       0       10      "|"   57    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx57                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
58      SQLCHAR       0       50      "|"   58    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx58                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
59      SQLCHAR       0       50      "|"   59    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx59                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
60      SQLCHAR       0       35      "|"   60    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx60                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
61      SQLCHAR       0       35      "|"   61    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx61                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
62      SQLCHAR       0       35      "|"   62    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx62                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
63      SQLCHAR       0       35      "|"   63    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx63                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
64      SQLCHAR       0       25      "|"   64    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx64                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
65      SQLCHAR       0       2       "|"   65    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx65                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
66      SQLCHAR       0       10      "|"   66    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx66                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
67      SQLCHAR       0       10      "|"   67    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx67                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
68      SQLCHAR       0       50      "|"   68    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx68                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
69      SQLCHAR       0       20      "|"   69    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx69                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
70      SQLCHAR       0       50      "|"   70    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx70                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
71      SQLCHAR       0       35      "|"   71    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx71                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
72      SQLCHAR       0       35      "|"   72    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx72                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
73      SQLCHAR       0       20      "|"   73    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx73                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
74      SQLCHAR       0       2       "|"   74    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx74                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
75      SQLCHAR       0       5       "|"   75    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx75                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
76      SQLCHAR       0       10      "|"   76    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx76                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
77      SQLCHAR       0       50      "|"   77    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx77                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
78      SQLCHAR       0       8       "|"   78    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx78                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
79      SQLCHAR       0       8       "|"   79    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx79                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
80      SQLCHAR       0       1       "\r\n"   80    xxxxxxxxxxx80                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

The stored procedure is doing the following conversions on all fields:

char/varchar fields are being RTrim(IsNull(FieldName, ''))'d
datetime fields are being Convert(VarChar(8), [DateField], 112)'d

What is happening is null date fields are being exported as "||", while null char/varchar fields are being exported as "| |" where the space is a null character (00). What I want is no null characters in the file, and I can't figure out why BCP is converting a blank value to 00. Is there any way to correct this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a resolution to this issue using the native BCP app, so I wrote a command line program in C# to properly export null char/varchar fields as 0-byte fields instead of a single null byte.